# DLL version clashes in different NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

In my solution some projects reference the "MahApps" NuGet package, which includes 'System.Windows.Interactivity.dll' **4.5.0.0**. Some projects also reference the "Prism" NuGet package, which includes 'System.Windows.Interactivity.dll' **4.0.0.0**.

The app.config has a binding redirect of "0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" to "4.5.0.0" by the way.

A handful of projects reference *both* NuGet packages, and looking in their "References" lists some of them have S.W.I v4.5.0.0 while others have v4.0.0.0. (I'm guessing this randomness is down to the order in which the packages were installed to the projects).

Sometimes the solution will build and run fine, but if only make a code change in one of the projects referencing S.W.I 4.0.0.0 then I get a runtime error along the lines of "v4.5.0.0 could not be found". v4.0.0.0 is being copied to the build output folder but my binding redirect is telling it to expect 4.5.0.0.

Any thoughts on a solution? I *could* try uninstalling and reinstalling the packages in the projects causing the issue, to see if I can get them to reference the 4.5.0.0 in the MahApps package, but my concern is that this may not be guaranteed to work during a package restore, screwing it up for another developer (or the build server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to Prism 6, which includes no DLLs other than its own. Thankfully it was a straightforward job.

I also had to remove the MahApps package then add it again, to get Visual Studio to add that package's System.Windows.Interactivity.dll (4.5.0.0).